# Getting junk value in kafka res api response

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I am using rest api to get the topic if from the kafka instance on confluent cloud

I am using below curl command

```
curl "http://(myhost):9092/topics/(topicname)" --output op.txt
```

but I am getting junk value in `op.txt` like

```
"U^C^C^@^B^BP"
```

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use REST to consume from Confluent Cloud (yet). With your data in Confluent Cloud you can use tools like [`ccloud`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ccloud-cli/index.html) or `kafkacat` to access your data from the commandline.

### Confluent Cloud CLI (`ccloud`)

```sh
$ ccloud kafka topic consume --from-beginning rmoff_test_topic_01
Starting Kafka Consumer. ^C or ^D to exit
Hello world!
This is a message on a topic in Confluent Cloud
```

### kafkacat

You can run kafkacat locally, or use it from Docker.

```sh
docker run --rm --interactive edenhill/kafkacat:1.6.0 \
            -X security.protocol=SASL_SSL -X sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN \
            -X ssl.ca.location=./etc/ssl/cert.pem -X api.version.request=true \
            -b $CCLOUD_BROKER_HOST \
            -X sasl.username="$CCLOUD_API_KEY" \
            -X sasl.password="$CCLOUD_API_SECRET" \
            -t rmoff_test_topic_01 -C -u -e
Hello world!
This is a message on a topic in Confluent Cloud
```

You can also output the message in JSON which can be useful:

```sh
docker run --rm --interactive edenhill/kafkacat:1.6.0 \
            -X security.protocol=SASL_SSL -X sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN \
            -X ssl.ca.location=./etc/ssl/cert.pem -X api.version.request=true \
            -b $CCLOUD_BROKER_HOST \
            -X sasl.username="$CCLOUD_API_KEY" \
            -X sasl.password="$CCLOUD_API_SECRET" \
            -t rmoff_test_topic_01 -C -u -J -e
```

```js
{
  "topic": "rmoff_test_topic_01",
  "partition": 0,
  "offset": 0,
  "tstype": "create",
  "ts": 1604571163960,
  "broker": 7,
  "key": null,
  "payload": "Hello world!"
}
{
  "topic": "rmoff_test_topic_01",
  "partition": 3,
  "offset": 0,
  "tstype": "create",
  "ts": 1604571168723,
  "broker": 1,
  "key": null,
  "payload": "This is a message on a topic in Confluent Cloud"
}
```